DocumentAI: 400 Request contains an invalid argument
If I run this code locally it works. On Cloud Run, I get "400 Request contains an invalid argument".
As side notes:

The input file path is a temporary file obtained using the get_file_path function (e.g. /tmp/20240524_1011_470558_393480997312_ME7001b9a160047278515b83ff123c7545.jpg)
Env variables are the same locally and on Cloud Run
Assign mime type correctly returns "image/jpeg"

How do I fix it?
def get_file_path(filename):
        """Create a secure version of the filename
        and return a full path to temporary directory"""
        file_name = secure_filename(filename)
        return os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), file_name)

def process_document_sample(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    file_path: str,
    mime_type: str,
    field_mask: Optional[str] = None,
    processor_version_id: Optional[str] = None,
) -> None:

    # You must set the `api_endpoint` if you use a location other than "us".
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient.from_service_account_json(
        config.Config.OCR_GCP_KEY_PATH, client_options=opts
    )

    logger.debug("Document AI Client correctly launched.")

    if processor_version_id:
        # The full resource name of the processor version, e.g.:
        # `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}/processorVersions/{processor_version_id}`
        name = client.processor_version_path(
            project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version_id
        )
    else:
        # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
        # `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}`
        name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    logger.debug("Local image correctly loaded.")

    # Load binary data
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type)

    # For more information: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProcessOptions
    # Optional: Additional configurations for processing.
    process_options = documentai.ProcessOptions(
        # Process only specific pages
        individual_page_selector=documentai.ProcessOptions.IndividualPageSelector(
            pages=[1]
        )
    )

    # Configure the process request
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
        name=name,
        raw_document=raw_document,
        field_mask=field_mask,
        process_options=process_options,
    )

    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    # For a full list of `Document` object attributes, reference this page:
    # https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document
    document = result.document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    logger.debug("The document contains the following text:")
    logger.debug(document.text)

    return document


document = process_document_sample(
            project_id=os.environ["GCP_PROJECT_ID"],
            location=os.environ["PROCESSOR_LOCATION"],
            processor_id=os.environ["PROCESSOR_ID"],
            file_path=file_path,
            mime_type=_assign_mime_type(file_path),
        )


Are you deploying this as a Cloud Run job? It won't work as a Cloud Run service because it does not appear to serve HTTP.

You should try to not use from_service_account_json and instead use Application Default Credentials. It's not your biggest issue but it would make your code safer and more flexible.

I'm invoking it from Cloud Run. The error is the same across platforms though (e.g. Digital Ocean)

Your code isn't a minimal repro so it's challenging to comment but ... content=image_content appears incorrect. This value should be base64-encoded (see RawDocument)

The downloaded object sent to DocumentAI was empty, due to external API-related circumstances; thus, the error.
Problem fixed with proper file download.
